# Using setfacl to create recursive permissions for Apache with rsync

Tags: debian, permissions, rsync, acl

I have a Dokuwiki installation locally, which I regularly sync to my server with rsync. I'm also going to give a friend of mine an ssh account, and host his public Dokuwiki installation. However, I'm having a problem with access permissions - even though the mirror is read-only, Dokuwiki still needs write-permissions to the data directory for cache etc. The Apache server runs as user www-data, and every time I do a rsync, it resets permissions.

Based on some other answers on this site, I tried using setfacl to set default permissions, but it doesn't seem to work - getfacl indicates that the permissions exist, but Dokuwiki won't run, and when I try to write a file as user www-data, it also doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
wiki/data$ sudo su www-data
$ pwd
/var/www/wiki/data
$ whoami
www-data
$ touch hi
touch: cannot touch `hi': Permission denied
$ getfacl /var/www/wiki/data
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/www/wiki/data
# owner: stian
# group: admin
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Here's the command I used to set the permissions:

```
setfacl -R -d -m u:www-data:7 /var/www/*
```

Comment: What command are you using with rsync? Default ACLs should apply. Also please show the ACL of a sample file.

Answer (score 4):

#### Issue #1: Rsync is dropping ACLs

After applying the ACL permissions you need to take care that when you perform your `rsync` that you're using either the `-A` or `--acls` switch. This instructs `rsync` to make sure to preserve these when doing the sync.

*excerpt from rsync man page*

```
    -A, --acls                  preserve ACLs (implies -p)
```

#### Issue #2: No ACL permissions

In looking at your example it does contain permissions as follows.

*traditional perms*

```
# owner: stian
# group: admin
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

*ACLs*

```
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

But these ACLs are for the creation of new objects, and don't work exactly the way you think. You need to still create an entry for user `www-data` in addition to the default ACL perms.

#### Example

```
$ pwd
/tmp/somedir

$ mkdir data
$ setfacl -R -d -m u:gopher:7 data

$ getfacl data
# file: data
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:gopher:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

#### An experiment

Now let's try and write a file to the `data` directory as user `gopher`.

```
$ sudo -u gopher touch /tmp/somedir/data/afile
touch: cannot touch `/tmp/somedir/data/afile': Permission denied
```

Look familiar?

#### Adding additional ACL permissions

It's because you need to add a ACL for the user `www-data`, the default rules aren't for access, they're for creating new files/directories.

```
$ setfacl -R -m u:gopher:7 data
```

Now check the `data` directory again:

```
$ getfacl data
# file: data
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:gopher:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:gopher:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

The only difference we now have a ACL saying that user `gopher` has `rwx` access:

```
user:gopher:rwx
```

#### Repeat the experiment

Try writing a data to the directory again:

```
$ sudo -u gopher touch /tmp/somedir/data/afile
$
```

It worked!!! Double check the resulting file:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/somedir/data/afile
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 gopher gopher 0 Oct  7 21:36 /tmp/somedir/data/afile
```

Comment: That makes sense but if you look at the code above, using getfacl, it does list that the file has the appropriate permissions?

Comment: @StianHåklev No, the file doesn't have the appropriate permissions. It has no ACL beyond the traditional unix permissions, and belongs to the user `stian`, not `www-data`. The default ACLs are only applied to newly created files; rsync sets the permissions based on the permissions on the source side. `rsync -A` will copy ACLs if you have the same ACLs on the source machine, is that the case?